# Getting error while accessing the Private Nuget feed

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package, private-nuget-feed

I am getting an error while trying to access the private NuGet feed from Azure Package artifacts.

`Install-Package Microsoft.Sdk -version 1.0.0-CI-20191028-053209`

```
The content at 'https://mp.visualstudio.com/Tools/_packaging?_a=feed&feed=Release/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Sdk'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' is not valid XML.
  For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.
  GET https://mp.visualstudio.com/Tools/_packaging?_a=feed&feed=ocpdirectory%40Release/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Sdk'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
  NonAuthoritativeInformation https://mp.visualstudio.com/Tools/_packaging?_a=feed&feed=ocpdirectory%40Release/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Sdk'&semVerLevel=2.0.0 429ms
Install-Package : Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.Sdk' from remote source 'https://mpneng.visualstudio.com/Tools/_packa
ging?_a=feed&feed=Release/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Sdk'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  The content at 'https://mp.visualstudio.com/Tools/_packaging?_a=feed&feed=Release/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Sdk'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' is not valid XML.
  For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass 
the settings into XmlReader.Create method.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.Sdk -version 1.0.0-CI-2019102 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The content at 'https://mp.visualstudio.com/Tools/_packaging?_a=feed&feed=Release/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Sdk'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' is not valid XML.`

According to the error log, it seems that you are using wrong URL, we should using the URL provided in the '**Connect to feed**' instructions.

Sample URL link

```
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_packaging/{artifact name}/nuget/v3/index.json
```

Comment: Yes, you were right issue with the URL only , I corrected the URL, and its working fine now. @Vito thanks for the help,